# Why aren't my line showing up on my ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm attaching an ObservableCollection to it filled with a class I created. The ObservableCollection begins empty but is filled once the file is loaded. I've checked and it's properly loading the CanvasStart and CanvasEnd values. As far as I was aware the ItemsControl should be updating itself when the points are added to the ObservableCollection. See below:

my CanvasLine class:

```
public class CanvasLine
    {
        public Point DxfStart { get; set; }
        public Point DxfEnd { get; set; }
        public Point CanvasStart { get; set; }
        public Point CanvasEnd { get; set; }
        public string Layer { get; set; }
        public List<double> Extents { get; set; }
        public double Scale { get; set; }
        public double CanvasWidth { get; set; }
        public double CanvasHeight { get; set; }

        public CanvasLine(Point dxfStart, Point dxfEnd, string layer)
        {
            DxfStart= dxfStart;
            DxfEnd= dxfEnd;
            Layer = layer;
        }

        public void GetCanvasLines(List<double> extents, double canvasWidth, double canvasHeight)
        {
            Extents = extents;
            CanvasWidth = canvasWidth; 
            CanvasHeight = canvasHeight;

            CanvasStart = DXFToCanvas.DXFCoordToCanvas(DxfStart, Extents, CanvasWidth, CanvasHeight);
            CanvasEnd = DXFToCanvas.DXFCoordToCanvas(DxfEnd, Extents, CanvasWidth, CanvasHeight);
        }
```

```
public partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private List<double> extents;
        private double scale;
        private ObservableCollection<CanvasLine> canvasLines = new ObservableCollection<CanvasLine>();

        public List<double> Extents
        {
            get { return extents; }
            set
            {
                extents = value;
            }
        }
        public double Scale
        {
            get { return scale; }
            set { scale = value; }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<CanvasLine> CanvasLines
        {
            get { return canvasLines; }
            set
            {
                canvasLines = value;
            }
        }
        
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public void LoadCanvasDXF()
        {
            extents = LoadDXF.LoadExtents(Globals.CAD_FILE_PATH);
            scale = LoadDXF.GetScale(extents, MainPageCanvas.Height, MainPageCanvas.Width);
            
            foreach (CanvasLine canvasLine in Globals.LINE_LIST)
            {
                canvasLine.GetCanvasLines(Extents, MainPageCanvas.Width, MainPageCanvas.Height);
                CanvasLines.Add(canvasLine);
            }
        }
    }
```

XAML for the ItemsControl:

```
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CanvasLines}" x:Name="MainPageCanvas" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="600" Height="300">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <Canvas Background="White"  Width="600" Height="300"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Line X1="{Binding CanvasStart.X}" Y1="{Binding CanvasStart.Y}"
                                X2="{Binding CanvasStart.X}" Y2="{Binding CanvasStart.Y}"
                                Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
```

Here is an example of a few of the lines start and end:

```
CanvasStart: 428.88814432501835, 266.5502781209483 CanvasEnd: 349.5791140550308, 266.5502781209483
CanvasStart: 349.5791140550308, 268.2016894748275 CanvasEnd: 428.88814432501835, 268.2016894748275
CanvasStart: 272.29306269353776, 268.2016894748275 CanvasEnd: 341.6523395564147, 268.2016894748275
CanvasStart: 341.6523395564147, 266.5502781209483 CanvasEnd: 272.29306269353776, 266.5502781209483
```

I tried binding the collection to my ItemsControl but it isn't working.

Comment: May be bind `CanvasEnd` coordinate to `X2`, `Y2`?

Comment: I was hoping that would've fixed it but unfortunately it's still not working.